# Rails AJAX upload form with Remotipart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, upload

I've been bashing my head trying to get an AJAX upload form working. I'm using Rails 3.2. I put `gem "remotipart", "~> 1.0"` in my Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and it installed successfully.

I previously had this non-ajax upload form, which I added `:remote => true` to as per the literature on the [github page](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) :

```
<%= form_tag "/administration/data_imports", :multipart => true, :remote => true %>  
    <label for="file">Input File</label> <%= file_field_tag "file" %>
    <button type="submit">Import Data</button>
</form>
```

and this in my `data_imports_controller` `create` action:

```
def create
  file = params[:file]
  filename = file.original_filename
end
```

I added a javascript include on my page for `jquery.remotipart.js` because it felt essential, albeit there being no explicit instruction to do so..

I tried it and it failed giving a server error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/data_imports_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

It's clear I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I need a hand.

Comment: Can you please paste your new view file after you made changes by adding `:remote => true` option

Comment: Please try using the answer below.. The problem is with how you are declaring your multipart option

Comment: If someone wants to recommend me an answer to tick, go ahead. I gave up the ghost on this idea a long time ago and never really achieved a satisfactory solution so I'm not sure which is the best answer, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

After a ton of debugging and reading through lots of code, I finally have the latest gem (1.0.2) working with Rails 3.2.8. I was nailed by three gotchas:

1. I was disabling my file input field prior to form submission and this causes remotipart to ignore it for inclusion in the iframe submission. You must make sure your file inputs are enabled. This is probably what you are seeing, and why specifying a different selector for the 'files' attribute works for you.
2. In the course of my debugging, I was overriding jquery.iframe-transport with the latest upstream source and it doesn't have support for the X-Http-Accepts hidden variable in the iframe. You must use the version bundled with the remotipart gem.
3. Don't forget to wire up a callback for ajax:complete on the form if you are using a datatype other than 'script'. This is the default if you don't specify dataType in the global ajax options, or use the data-type attribute on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky you. I had the exact same problem some time ago. :) Add this to your application.js:

```
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require jquery.iframe-transport
```

You can get the 'iframe-transport' file from here: http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/.

And as I said as a comment to another answer: I believe `:multipart` isn't needed, because you're using Rails 3.2. Not 100% sure, because I'm still using Rails 3.1 at work. ;)

Hope it helps!

## Edit

I created an example app showing how to add remotipart to enable AJAX file uploading. It works great for me.

https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/remotipart_example

See the commits inside that repository for the steps that were taken.

Comment: I'll give this a blast tomorrow morning, as I'm just leaving work. I've never seen those require statements, do I just stick them at the top of application.js?

Comment: You're using the asset pipeline right? If not you should just use javascript_include_tag to add those two files. Make sure it's added after jquery is included.

Comment: That's too bad. Tomorrow, I'll try and recreate your problem and see if I can get it working using those two lines. I'll post it to Github. :)

Comment: I created a repository on Github. Check it out. :)

Comment: This should be submitted as a ticket for remotipart.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to achieve something along the lines of what I wanted by bodging in a way I don't really understand but hey, it kinda works. I had to add some jQuery along the lines of:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(this.action, {
        files: $(":file", this),
        iframe: true
    }).complete( function(data) {
        eval(data.responseText);
    });
});
```

Which I believe takes over the form submission, initiates an ajax post with this iframe-transport lark and then evaluates what is returned (because in my case I'm returning javascript). I also had to remove `:remote => true` from the form else it was posting twice or something.

Thought I'd post that here so that it can either help someone out or lead someone to doing it better.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the old version of `jquery.iframe-transport.js`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are actually declaring your `:multipart=> true`

Please use the code below and your form will then accept the file parameter.

```
 form_for "/administration/data_imports",:remote => true,:html => {:multipart => true}
```

Comment: He's using form_tag, so he doesn't need to add :html. And he's using Rails 3.2, so defining :multipart isn't needed anyway.