# Rails 4 ActionController::UnknownFormat error in Update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting the following error when I call an Update method.

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/devise/custom/registrations_controller.rb:21:in `update_avatar'
```

Here's the offending controller:

```
class Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def update_avatar
    @user = current_user

    if @user.update(user_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_avatar'}
        flash[:notice] = "Updated user"
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  protected
    def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end
end
```

What's odd is I use this approach on other controllers without a hitch and yet here it falls over on the respond_to line.

Can anyone shed any light? Thanks!

**Log**

> Processing by Devise::Custom::RegistrationsController#update_avatar as
>   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"reTaOwTtvbI+IPYq1nvLWl0blVOmaSu/o5VpfGziguo=",
>   "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript,
>   application/javascript, application/ecmascript,
>   application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
>   "user"=>{"avatar"=>#,
>   @original_filename="translate.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\";
>   filename=\"translate.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}

Comment: Can you look in your log and add the first couple of lines of output from processing the action?  It should look something like this example from my log `Processing LessonsController#online_xml [GET]\n
Parameters: {"id"=>"57978"}`

Comment: Is this relevant at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954122/rails-ajax-upload-form-with-remotipart

Comment: Thanks, I have this installed already. It's uploading the file fine and saving to the db, just not processing the format.js to call my ajax request.

Comment: Maybe it's being processed as an html request for some reason?  Try adding `format.html { raise 'We got an HTML request'}`

Comment: Hmm, no - not doing that either. I'm thinking maybe something to do with the fact that it's a custom devise controller? Though can't see what difference it'd make to this...

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Comment: Not yet - still working this through. Appreciate the help though Pavan. Need to go back to basics, strip it down and figure out what the hell I'm doing wrong before I hassle you guys further :-D

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is due to this line  `render 'edit'`.You should be specifying a **`format`** when using **`respond_to`**.

Update your **`update_avatar`** method to like this

```
def update_avatar
  @user = current_user

  if @user.update(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_avatar'}
      flash[:notice] = "Updated user"
    end
  else
    format.html { render 'edit' } # here
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it could be a routing issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013865/rails-4-routing-best-practice

Comment: @steve Definitely not! See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943892/actioncontrollerunknownformat?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The part `{ render 'update_avatar'}` in `format.js { render 'update_avatar'}` is not needed, as it will try to load the file called `update_avatar.js` by default.

Do you actually have such js file?

You could also test with something like: `format.js {render "alert('Hello World');"`} just to see if it's working.

Comment: Thanks, yep, I do - normally if the file wasn't there I'd see a different error. It would not fail on the respond_to line like it is here. It's not reaching the format.js line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
format.js { render 'update_avatar',
        flash[:notice] = "Updated user"}
```

and btw deyan is right! format.js renders renders update_avatar.js by default you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to completely rewrite the custom controller. I followed this guide: http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/ and re-factored my code accordingly. It also helps to understand more about Devise before tackling things like this!

Thanks though for the all the contributions. Best place on the web to get help, hands down!